# Access files from local machine

Tags: javascript, html, activex, activexobject

I need to access list of files in "D//logs" folder from my machine using javascript.
And then display them as hyperlink in a html page. I tried to acheive this using ActiveX, but accessing files is throwing error.

(Developing only for Internet explorer)

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var xx = fso.GetFolder("d:\\logs");
var yy = new Enumerator(xx.Files); 
var zz =  new Enumerator(yy.item()); // how to acess files inside folder
```

Comment: you need to install https://nodejs.org/en/ and use that like backend system, dump that activex object!

Comment: can you brief please

Comment: activex object will only work in internet explorer, any other browser will fail! so I advise to use persistent node, or andother backend system to access logs..

Comment: forgot to mention it in question. I'm developing only for IE now, I have less time, so trying with activeX. Also I dont have any backend system for now,. :(